# Automate Jenkins deployment with different build no

Tags: jenkins

I have jenkins configured on following way..

1 - Source code build   ( Build #1 ) 

2 - Deploy source code to Dev using source code build no ( Build #1 )

3 - Deploy source code to QA using source code build no ( Build  #1 )

4 - Deploy Source code to Prod using source code build no ( Once QA Pass ) 

5 - Deploy Same source code build ( the one we deployed to Prod ) to a Prod backup server.

I wondering is there any easy way that i can automate the production backup server 
deployment, once the production deployment is completed successfully with same source code.

I have configure the build view plugin to accomplish this. But the challenge for me is, production backup job is triggering the build no of production deployment job not the source code build no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the production backup server deployment to a downstream Jenkins Build #2 which can accept the `${BUILD_TAG}` of your source control from the Build #1.

On the Build #2 you can used the passed BUILD_TAG to deploy the same source code build.

You can accomplish the passing of parameter using the plugin [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).